# React Native wait for one API call to finish before executing any others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm writing an app in react native that needs to make a call to an API to receive a bearer token that it will use for all other API calls but I'm having difficulty making sure that the call to get the token finishes before any other calls are made.

I have a basic `APIHelper` class which is going to contain wrapper functions for all the API calls the app needs to make, here's a reduced version of it:

```
export class APIHelper {
    constructor(baseURL) {
        this.baseURL = baseURL;
        this.token = null;
    }

    setToken(token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    getToken(username, password) {
        var url = this.baseURL + `/token/${username}/${password}`;
        fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            header: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }).then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setToken(data["access_token"]);
            });
    }

    getRequest(endpoint) {
        fetch(this.baseUrl + endpoint, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.token
            }
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is a reduced version of my `App.js`:

```
var apiHelper = new APIHelper("URLGoesHere");

class StarterApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    apiHelper.getToken("UsernameGoesHere", "PasswordGoesHere");
    var users = apiHelper.getRequest("/users");
    console.log(users);
    return (
      //App Content Here
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried a number of different things: Making the API calls asynchronous, instituting a check in the `getRequest` function to wait until `token` isn't `null` but that just seems to hang, moving the calls into the constructor for the App. Is what I'm looking to do possible? Or will I need to make a call to get the token every time I want to make an API call?

Also: I understand that this is not a particularly secure API, it's a temporary system for a school project, please do not provide feedback on that.

Comment: Return each fetch call from the functions, then use `async render()` and `await apiHelper.getToken(...)`, thus the next line will only run after the fetch has finished.

Comment: I've tried this but React Native doesn't seem to like `render()` being `async`

Comment: Right, you're not supposed to do this in `render()`. Do it in `componentDidMount()`, then set state accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you return the fetch calls which are promises from getRequest, getToken you can ensure that the call to getToken completes before getRequest using await. Also run the code in componentDidMount as suggested by Chris G e.g.

```
export class APIHelper {
constructor(baseURL) {
    this.baseURL = baseURL;
    this.token = null;
}

setToken(token) {
    this.token = token;
}

getToken(username, password) {
    var url = this.baseURL + `/token/${username}/${password}`;
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        header: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            this.setToken(data["access_token"]);
        });
}

getRequest(endpoint) {
    return fetch(this.baseUrl + endpoint, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.token
        }
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
}

var apiHelper = new APIHelper("URLGoesHere");

class StarterApp extends React.Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            await apiHelper.getToken("UsernameGoesHere", "PasswordGoesHere");
            await var users = apiHelper.getRequest("/users");
            console.log(users);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            //App Content Here
        );
    }
}
```